# Input of multiple char arrays isn't working

Tags: c, scanf, newline, c-strings, conversion-specifier

```
char toFind[100];
char replace[100];
int pos = 0;
printf("Enter a text: ");
scanf("%[^\n]", str);
printf("Enter a search pattern: ");
scanf("%[^\n]", toFind);
printf("Enter a substitute: ");
scanf("%[^\n]", replace);
pos = strnfnd(0, toFind);
strins(pos, replace);
printf("Der Text ist: %s", str);
```

This code sample let me read the value for str but skips the other two scanf. I have no idea why.
What can I do to fix this?

Ps: str is a global char array

Comment: Quick fix: Put a space before `%[^n]` in the second and third calls to `scanf()`. But you would probably be better off using `fgets()` instead. There are plenty of similar questions here already.

Comment: Please change `"%[^\n]"` to `" %[^\n]"` with the added space to filter the previous newline in the input buffer. It's harmless in the first one.

Comment: What is `str`? What are `strnfnd` and `strins`, if latter are not relevant to the question, why are they in your code? Please read this: [mcve]

Comment: what is strins ?

Comment: Seems to me that you should consider using `fgets` instead of `scanf`

Comment: [Don't use scanf](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Comment: @Jabberwocky they are methodes

Comment: This issue is discussed more than enough times, but ppl don't know what exactly to search for. I know because I was there. I think anyone teaching C should cover this issue when discussing scanf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%[^\n]", str);
```

the new line character `'\n'` still is present in the input buffer.

So the next call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%[^\n]", toFind);
```

that reads input until the new line character `'\n'` is encountered reads nothing.

You should write for example

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str);
```

to remove the new line character `'\n'` from the input buffer.

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char s[100];
    
    scanf( "%99[^\n]%*c", s );
    puts( s );
    
    scanf( "%99[^\n]", s );
    puts( s );

    return 0;
}
```

In this case if to enter strings for example like

```
Hello
      World
```

then the output will be

```
Hello
      World
```

Another and more simple approach is to prepend the format string with a blank. For example

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", toFind);
      ^^^^
```

In this case all leading white space characters will be skipped.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char s[100];
    
    scanf( "%99[^\n]", s );
    puts( s );
    
    scanf( " %99[^\n]", s );
    puts( s );

    return 0;
}
```

In this case if to enter strings as shown above that is

```
Hello
      World
```

then the program output will be

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: You don't need the `%*c` kludge to remove the newline (will *must* remove *one* character). The `scanf` does have the filter you also mention.

Comment: @WeatherVane But sometimes leading spaces are required. in the input string:)

Comment: True, the format string doesn't discriminate, and in that case `fgets` might be better.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you run the compiled code - the operating system. In some cases when the "Enter" key is pressed, two bytes are emitted in the input stream (10 and 13) instead of '\n' (10). In that case you need to flush the extra symbols. Check the comments for the exact implementation.

Comment: Adding the space will filter *any amount* of whitespace in the input stream (including none). Whether there were 1 or 2 characters for the newline isn't relevant, since OP hasn't flushed any of them.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with your `scanf()` usage: `scanf("%[^\n]", str);`

- you do not specify the maximum number of characters to store into `str`, hence a sufficiently long line typed by the user will cause undefined behavior. This is a typical software flaw hackers can try and exploit. You can prevent this by specifying the limit as `scanf("%99[^\n]", str);`
- you do not read the trailing newline entered by the user, so the next call `scanf("%[^\n]", toFind);` will fail because no characters different from `'\n'` are present in the input stream, since the first pending byte is `'\n'`, or `EOF`.
- you do not check the return value of the `scanf()` calls, so you cannot detect input errors such as the above.
- note however that `scanf("%99[^\n]", str);` will fail if the user types enter immediately and `str` will not be modified in this case.

It is much safer to use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` for this task:

```
char str[100];
char toFind[100];
char replace[100];
int pos = 0;
printf("Enter a text: ");
if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
    printf("input error\n");
    return 1;
}
str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0'; /* strip the trailing newline if any */
printf("Enter a search pattern: ");
if (!fgets(toFind, sizeof toFind, stdin)) {
    printf("input error\n");
    return 1;
}
toFind[strcspn(toFind, "\n")] = '\0'; /* strip the trailing newline if any */
printf("Enter a substitute: ");
if (!fgets(replace, sizeof replace, stdin)) {
    printf("input error\n");
    return 1;
}
replace[strcspn(replace, "\n")] = '\0'; /* strip the trailing newline if any */
pos = strnfnd(0, toFind);
strins(pos, replace);
printf("Der Text ist: %s\n", str);
```